# Castle Windsor - Register all Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, castle-windsor, autofac

This is the way how to do it with autofac

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
    .Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Form)));
```

or

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
    .AssignableTo<Form>();
```

How to do this with Castle Windsor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (typing from memory):

```
container.Register(
   Classes.FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
      .BasedOn<Form>()
      .Configure(c => c.Lifestyle.Transient)
);
```

The `Configure` option isn't required, but my win forms are usually transient.

Check out the [registration docs](http://docs.castleproject.org//Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx) for more options.